# Alignment of all lines in question environment and check mark for correct answer

Tags: exam, alignment

I am preparing a question paper in document class exam and I need help in following issues

1. In every question, second line starts from slight left below the first line. I want all lines of the question aligned with first line and not being able to do so.
2. Instead of giving solution in separate line (on using \printanswers), is there any way to get check mark on correct answer after using \printanswers?
3. As I have used task to write options along 2 rows, is there any way to get checkboxes along 2 rows?
4. Is there any way to fill checkbox corresponding to correct answer?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\date{}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[top=0.6in, bottom=1in, left=0.6in, right=0.55in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{multicol,adjustbox}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\title{\vspace{-1.6cm}\bfseries\huge \fbox{\fbox{DAILY PRACTICE PROBLEM}} \\[3mm]
    \Large  \fbox{XYZ}\\[5mm] \hline\hline \vspace{0.3 cm}
    \normalsize  MM: 50 \hfill Duration : 30 minutes \hfill  DPP 1 \vspace{0.3 cm} \hline \hline
}
\settasks{label=(\alph*), label-width=1.5em}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Answer:}\enspace}
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{red}}

%\printanswers


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\vspace{-2.8 cm}

\begin{center}

 \subsection*{\Large{IMPORTANT INSTRUCTIONS}}   
\end{center}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{2pt}
\begin{enumerate}\singlespacing \small
 \item Section A contains TEN objective type question having only one option correct. Each question carries $4$ marks.
 \item  Section B contains FIVE True/False questions. Each question carries $2$ marks.
 \item In section A, $4$ marks will be awarded for marking correct answer, $-1$ for marking incorrect answer and $0$ marks for not marking the answer.
 \item There is no negative marking in section B .

\end{enumerate}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}

{ \fontsize{12}{14.4}\selectfont
\begin{center}
\cellwidth{0.3cm}
\hqword{\textbf{Question:}}
\hpword{\textbf{Marks Allotted:}}
\hsword{\textbf{Marks Obtained:}}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\end{center}
\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
}
\vspace{-1.5 cm}
\begin{center}
   \section*{\ovalbox{\Large{SECTION A}}}  
\end{center}

\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont
\begin{questions}
\pointformat{}
\question[4] The set of intelligent students in a class is :

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task A null set 
\task A singleton set
\task A finite set
\task Not a well defined collection
\end{tasks} 
\begin{solution}
(d)
\end{solution}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\question[4] If $n(U)=700$, $n(A)=200$, $n(B)=300$ and $n(A \cap B)=100$, then value of $n(A^c \cap B^c)$ is :

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $400$
\task $600$
\task $300$
\task $200$
\end{tasks}

\begin{solution}
(c)
\end{solution}




\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Note that you actually ask four questions.

Comment: Off-topic, but in the `documentclass` you must write `a4paper`, not `a4peper`.

Comment: For creating worksheets you may take a look at the `xsim` package of  Clemens Niederberger on future occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first point:

The `\question` macro is nothing more than an `\item` so normal list lengths apply. Add the following before the starting the `questions` environment.

```
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\itemindent}{-\labelsep}%
}
```

See also Section 4.10 of the `exam` documentation.

To your third point, use the `\settasks` macro:

```
\settasks{
   label = $\square$,
}
```

To your second and fourth point, a swift but not so sophisticated answer can be:

```
\def\correctlabel{%
\ifprintanswers$square$\else\color{red}$\checkmark\hspace{-.48cm}\square$\fi
}
```

Then use in the appropriate `\task` line:

```
\task[\correctlabel] null set
```